# Add badge progress indicators to Review start page

Tags: feature-request, review, badge-progress

Currently, it requires *7 clicks* to find out progress towards the [Custodian](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2278/custodian), [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer) and [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2279/steward) badges for all review tasks.

Can the progress indicators be added to the [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) start page?

[image]

Comment: 7 clicks from where? Starting on the review page, all one must do is click into the queue and *hover* over the indicator to make it expand. That's 1 click. I have no idea how you made it to 7.

Comment: @animuson 1 is *Review*. 2 is *First Posts*, 3 is *Late Answers*, 4 is *Low Quality Posts*, 5 is *Close Votes*, 6 is *Suggested Edits*, 7 is *Reopen Votes*... 7 clicks in total; not 1.

Comment: You should clarify that the 7 clicks is for *all* the queues. ;P I certainly didn't read it that way.

Comment: I really don't know how much clearer I can make this question. Since @animuson's comment, I edited the question to try to make it clearer, but since then, that comment has received 2 upvotes, and this question 1 downvote. So here's my plea: if you have the same problem as animuson, please **edit my question** to make it clearer, because I don't know how to clarify it any further, myself.

Comment: +1 for all the links for separate words. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've mocked up what would only require *1 click* to get the same information.

**Notice the addition of progress indicators** (taken from [within](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) [individual](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats) [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) [task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats)).

Can this be implemented? The functionality is already there, so it would be easy enough to do:

[image: a]